# Kernel of canonical projection

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $ U \subseteq V $ be a subvectorspace.

Then there exists a linear mapping

$$ f: V \rightarrow V/U , v \rightarrow \bar{v} $$

where $ker(f)=U$. **Why is the kernel equal to U?** I know you can use the dimension formula but let's not do that right now.

The zero vector in $V/U$ is $\bar{0}= 0+U=U$.

So basically, whenever I input an element of U into the canonical projection I get a sum of vectors, which are both in U. And since U is closed under addition this is also gonna be in U. Therefore, the whole thing is in U and equal to $\bar{0}$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x\in \ker f\Leftrightarrow f(x)=\bar{0}\Leftrightarrow x+U=0+U\Leftrightarrow x-0\in U\Leftrightarrow x\in U.$$ That is, $\ker f=U.$

Comment: $x+U=0+U\Leftrightarrow x-0\in U$ Could you explain why that is?

Comment: It is the definition of the equivalence relation on the quotient set $V/U$: $$x\sim y\Leftrightarrow x-y\in U.$$